# Groovy scope - how to access script variable in a method

Tags: groovy, scope

I have a question about scoping rules in Groovy. In the following snippet, I have three variables, `a` has local scope, `b` has script scope, and `c` should get script scope as well using the `@Field` annotation.

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
import groovy.transform.Field;

//println org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()

def a = 42;
b = "Tea"
@Field def c = "Cheese"

void func()
{
    // println a // MissingPropertyException
    println b // prints "Tea"
    println c // prints "Cheese" with groovy 2.1.2, MissingPropertyException with groovy 1.8.6

}

class Main
{
    def method()
    {
        // println a // MissingPropertyException
        // println b // MissingPropertyException
        // println c // MissingPropertyException with both 1.8.6. and 2.1.2
    }

}

func();
new Main().method();
```

I get `MissingPropertyException`s on the lines indicated with comments. The exceptions on `a` are expected, as that variable has local scope. But I would expect `b` to be accessible inside `method()` - it isn't.
`@Field` doesn't do anything in groovy 1.8.6, although after upgrading it works, so I guess that is an old bug. Nevertheless, `c` is inaccessible inside `method()` with either version.

So my questions are:

1. Why can't I access a variable annotated with `@Field` inside
   `method()`?
2. How can I refer to a script variable inside `method()`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you have methods or statements outside of a `class` declaration in a groovy script, an implicit class is created.  To answer your questions:

1. In your example, `func()` can access the field `c` because they are both members of the implicit class.  The `Main` class is not, so it can't.
2. You need to pass a reference to the script variable to `method()`.  One way is to pass the implicitly defined `binding` object, through which you can access all the script scope variables.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
import groovy.transform.Field;

//println org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()

def a = 42;
b = "Tea"
@Field def c = "Cheese"

void func()
{
    // println a // MissingPropertyException
    println b // prints "Tea"
    println c // prints "Cheese" with groovy 2.1.2, MissingPropertyException with groovy 1.8.6

}

class Main
{
    def scriptObject
    def binding

    def method()
    {
        // println a // MissingPropertyException
        println binding.b
        println scriptObject.c
    }
}

func();
new Main(scriptObject: this, binding: binding).method();
```

Comment: pretty sure you meant to pass those scriptObject and binding arguments to the constructor, a la "new Main( scriptObject: this, binding: binding ).method()"

Answer (score 11):

This script and `Main` are generated as two separate classes inside the same file.

As `Main` is not an internal class of the Script class, it cannot see the `java.lang.Object c` field inside the script class.

You would either have to explicitly wrap this script in a class with a `static main( args )` method (and an internal `Main` class) or you would need to pass an instance of the script class to the method like: `Main.method( this )`

This is the sort of thing that the above script generates:

```
class Script032034034 {
  Object c

  Script032034034() {
    c = 'Cheese'
  }

  Object run() {
    Object a = 42
    b = 'Tea'
    func()
    new Main().method()
  }

  void func() {
    println b
    println c
  }
}

class Main {
  Object method() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the generated code snippet, this helps my understanding a lot. My misunderstanding was that I thought that Main would be a subclass of Script032034034.

Comment: In the code you provided, how does `func()` "see" `b`?  Is `b` also a property of the Script class?