# access global variable in static scope

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to access global variable, declared in the script, from the static method of the class, declared in the same script?

For example

```
def s = "12345"

class MyClass {
    static def method() {
        println s
    }
}
```

Because that way it fails with the error

```
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context
```

which is expected though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a related discussion at this question:

[Groovy scope - how to access script variable in a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619216/groovy-scope-how-to-access-script-variable-in-a-method)

Related in that both questions refer to using a global variable within a class, but this question differs somewhat in that you are seeking to use a static method which alters how you pass the script instance or binding (2 choices).

*Passing the Script's Instance*

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def s = "12345"

class MyClass {
    static def method(si) {      
      return si.s
    }
}

assert MyClass.method(this) == "12345"
```

*Passing the Script's binding*

```
s = "12345" // NOTE: no 'def'

class MyClass {
    static def method(b) {      
      return b.s
    }
}

assert MyClass.method(binding) == "12345"
```

Comment: so basically as with the basic `java` approach? I thought that Groovy allows it to do somehow as it more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the problem is that in Groovy there is no such thing as a global variable. What is loosely considered a global variable is actually a static property within some class.

For example, if you remove the *println* line so that the code compiles, you get something like this out of the compiler:

```
public class script1455567284805 extends groovy.lang.Script { 

    ...

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        return java.lang.Object s = '12345'
    }

    ...

}

public class MyClass implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject extends java.lang.Object { 

    ...

    public static java.lang.Object method() {
        // This is where the println would have been.
        return null
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, an additional class is created and the the `s` variable is declared within the method `run()` of that class. This makes the variable inaccessible to your other class.

*Note: Removing the `def` will not address this issue.*

### Solution

Your best bet is to place your "global variables" into a class, possibly as static properties, like this:

```
class Global {
    static Object S = "12345"
}

class MyClass {
    static def method() {
        println Global.S
    }
}
```

Comment: oh! I completely forgot that `def` creates variables inside `run` method of the script. I should have declared variable without `def`. I think It might be possible to do with some custom AST transformation

Answer (score 1):

You included a variable type with the `s` variable (by using the `def` type). In a Groovy script, this is treated as a local variable - and local to the `run()` method that is generated - which is kind of like a `main()` class. As a result, the variable is not available in other methods or classes.

If you remove the `def` you will be able to make use of the `s` variable.

Here is the [Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_variables) that explains this further.