# gradle/groovy : calling a 'global' function from a custom Class

Tags: java, class, gradle, groovy

I'm new to groovy/gradle
As far as I understand gradle/groovy is compatible with java.

I wrote the following gradle (without any task)  in a 'build.gradle' file:

```
def myFun = {->"Hello World"}

class MyClass {
    String getLabel() {
        return ""+ myFun();
        }
    }

System.err.println(new MyClass().getLabel());
```

where a class `MyClass` calls the 'global'(?) function `myFun`.

Calling `gradle --tasks` produces the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tmp'.
> No signature of method: MyClass.myFun() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any(), every(), dump()

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.671 secs
```

How can I make this class `MyClass` to 'see' the function `myFun` ?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you meant `gradle tasks` and not `gradle --tasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly, since there are no global variables in Groovy. You can modify your declaration to pass an instance of the current class so you can invoke the `myFun` closure:

```
@groovy.transform.Field 
def myFun = {-> "Hello World"}

class MyClass {
    String getLabel(script) {
        return ""+ script.myFun();
    }
}

System.err.println(new MyClass().getLabel(this))
```

Or you can use the `binding` object, but it's the same pattern.

For more info:

- [Groovy scope - how to access script variable in a method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15619216/862594)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418596/862594