# Pass stage variable value in Mail body Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to pass the variable value from one stage to the mail body of jenkins. But the variable value is not reflecting.

The code works if I create another stage and call the variable. But not in the 
notifyStatusChangeViaEmail method block

Below is the example code.

```
def variable
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
options {
   timestamps()
   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS' )
}
  stages{
      stage('Variable'){
  steps {
    script{
  variable = "Hi, Build is successful"
      }
   }
  }
 }
}

def notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(prevBuild) {
def subject
def body

if (currentBuild.previousBuild != null) {
    switch (prevBuild.result) {
        case 'FAILURE':
            emailext attachLog: true, body: "${variable}", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Build Status : Build is back to Normal', to: 'sumith.waghmare@gmail.com';
            break

        case 'UNSTABLE':
            emailext attachLog: true, body: "${variable}", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Build Status : Build is back to Normal', to: 'sumith.waghmare@gmail.com';
            break

        case 'SUCCESS':
            emailext attachLog: true, body: "${variable}", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Build Status', to: 'sumith.waghmare@gmail.com';
            break
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable is not defined in the scope of the function (and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619216/groovy-scope-how-to-access-script-variable-in-a-method) explains how scope of functions works in groovy).

To fix the issue you're seeing I would either make `variable` a parameter of `notifyStatusChangeViaEmail`, or I would remove the `def variable` statement, because that would make `variable` a global variable and so the function would be able to access it.

Examples:

Making the variable, a parameter of `notifyStatusChangeViaEmail`:

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
options {
   timestamps()
   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS' )
}
  stages {
    stage('Send Email') {
      steps {
        script {
          def emailBody = "Hi, Build is successful"

          // I assume that prevBuild is defined somewhere already

          notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(prevBuild, emailBody)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(prevBuild, emailBody) {
  if (currentBuild.previousBuild != null) {
    switch (prevBuild.result) {
        case 'FAILURE':
            emailext attachLog: true, 
                     body: emailBody, 
                     recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']], 
                     subject: 'Build Status : Build is back to Normal', 
                     to: 'sumith.waghmare@gmail.com';
            break

      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Using `variable` as a global:

```
// --> I deleted the "def variable" line <--


pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
options {
   timestamps()
   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS' )
}
  stages {
    stage('Variable') {
      steps {
        script {
          // There is no "def" when you first assign a value to
          // `variable`, so it will become a global variable, 
          // which is a variable you can use anywhere in your file
          variable = "Hi, Build is successful"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
def notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(prevBuild) {
if (currentBuild.previousBuild != null) {
    switch (prevBuild.result) {
        case 'FAILURE':
            emailext attachLog: true, body: variable, recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Build Status : Build is back to Normal', to: 'sumith.waghmare@gmail.com';
            break

     //...
    }
  }
}
```

Using variable as a parameter:

Comment: I did not get what you said. Can you please send an example relevant to my problem?

Comment: I added some examples, I hope they can help you!